# Rotate an object with help of hand

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to rotate an object with my hand only in the Y axis. I am able to achieve this as well in my implementation.
The problem comes in saving the last rotation, when the hand tries to rotate the object again, the object's start rotation snaps to a new rotation completely.

How do I solve this problem?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RotateObj : MonoBehaviour {

    private Quaternion currentRot;
    private Vector3 startPos;
    public Transform hand;
    private bool offsetSet;

    void Start () {

    }

    void Update () {
        Rotate ();
    }

    void SetOffsets () {
        if (offsetSet)
            return;
            
        startPos = Vector3.Normalize (hand.transform.position - this.transform.position);
        currentRot = this.transform.rotation;
        
        offsetSet = true;
    }

    void Rotate () {
        SetOffsets ();

        Vector3 closestPoint = Vector3.Normalize (hand.transform.position - this.transform.position);
        var rot = Quaternion.FromToRotation (startPos, closestPoint);
        rot = Quaternion.Euler (0, rot.eulerAngles.y * 10f, 0);
        this.transform.rotation = rot * currentRot;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not really getting what are the supposed movements of the 'hand' nor the rotating object itself, but it seems like your code is doing the following:

- 'startPos' is just a direction from whatever you're rotating to the 'hand',
- 'closestPoint' is, surprisingly, created by the same operation, but assuming possible position change, in Update() could result in different value.
- Quaternion 'rot' you're creating is definitely describing some rotation, but the way of calculating it makes me doubt it has any sense here, because it describes the rotation of imaginary object at world zero that looks at startPos to be rotated in way to be looking at closestPoint,
- and then you just creating another rotation using only Y axial component of the previous multiplied by 10, finally adding it to the 'currentRot' which is set once in a SetOffsets() and never updated.

And here is the interesting part starts - how help yourself to percieve Quaternions trhough Vectors: stand in a center of the room, it's your [0,0,0], then pick a straight direction to a closest wall - it's your initial rotation (identity, also known as 'no-rotation'). Then select two objects in different corners, let's say its a chair and a flower. Look at the chair now. The rotation amount you need to apply to self to look from the chair to the flower can be described as quaternion, and if you'll using Quaternion.FromTo(), you'll feed it with a position of chair relative to you, and then position of the flower, also relative to you. Your 'up' direction could also change as a result of rotation if you tilt your head at the destination point.

To conclude, I see little sense in the code above and can advise you two things:

1. Please, describe a problem in a context, better with screenshots and maybe some sketches of what you're trying to achieve, because just words is not enough,
2. Please, watch couple tutorials on how to use quaternions in Unity, there is plenty of them. I know, Q's are seemingly tricky and mind blowing, but if you manage to abstract from the underlying math, its logic is very-very simple: like a segment on the line is representing the amount of travel along this line in one direction and inverted one - in another, the quaternion is representing the amount of rotation around point and axis. I found that the sphere is a best way to explain: imagine a sphere, the little dot on a surface of a sphere is a 'look direction' from its center, a little arrow from that point is a 'up' direction, the sphere itself is fixed on its center point so it can't move, thus any difference between two dot's positions and orientations (remember 'up' arrow) can be described by quaternion.